# Changing the Locale in WINE

Tags: linux, locale, wine

I'm using wine emulator on linux (SliTaz 4.0) and i want to change the wine locale so that the dialogs and messages are displayed in Japanese.

I found this tool http://code.google.com/p/winelocale/ which seems to do the job but I couldn't find a download link anywhere and could not contact the author, so does anybody know how to do that please?

I am not actually certain if this tool (WINELocale) will actually work, so I am open to any suggestions to change the locale of WINE to Japanese.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
LC_ALL="ja_JP"
```

another example to do it ;)

Comment: I think its something to do with Slitaz rather than WINE itself

Comment: well then, seams to be buging around (bad distri who hasnt official stuff?) or something is enforcing the lang

Comment: another way to debug: LANGUAGE=fr strace wine ./Myprog.exe 2>&1 | grep LC_MESSAGES       this will show which .mo files wine is trying to open on a program that uses GNU gettext for internationalization

Answer (score 18):

in Ubuntu 13.04 i had to use

```
LANG="ja_JP.UTF8" wine YourBinary.exe
```

Comment: 6 year passed, I am usint Ubuntu 16.04 and this command is still working.

Comment: fedora 29 x64. Default en_US.UTF8  for system. `LANG="zh_CN.UTF8" wine YourBinary.exe` and `LC_ALL="zh_CN.UTF8" wine YourBinary.exe` all work for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I had to edit `/etc/locale.gen` and un-comment these two lines:

```
ja_JP.EUC-JP EUC-JP
ja_JP.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

After that, I ran `locale-gen` (as root), and when it finished generating locales simply setting `LANG=ja_JP.utf8` worked. The key was generating locale information first, it seems.

Also, if you haven't got any, you'll need to install a japanese font on your system.

My distribution is Debian Sid, if anyone wonders, but I believe this is also what you need to do in Arch and Ubuntu and most other distros.

Answer (score 1):

```
export LANG="ja_JP"
```

after this wine changes its locale to japanese, altough remember to install fonts for japanese, otherwise it will look like garbage!

if u close the terminal, the settings for the locale will be lost.
a cleaner way would be:

```
LANG="ja_JP" winecfg
```

as example, so only this "process (and childs)" will be affected, remember to use it for wine too like this:

```
LANG="ja_JP" wine YourBinary.exe
```

Comment: I tried it, it did not work.. I had the fonts and did all the steps mentioned... Everything stayed in English

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the locale for all applications via Registry, by setting the `LC_ALL` environment variable in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment` (Right click -> New -> String value).

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, `export LANG="ja_JP"` should work.

But make sure you have that locale installed, or it won't. How to install it depends on your distribution, but to check whether it is available or not, you can simply run `locale -a` in a terminal and it will list the locales available for use.

Answer (score 0):

`LANG=ja_JP` doesn't seem default to utf8 on my machine. (Maybe because it's lower in locale.gen?)

`LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8` works.

Answer (score 0):

see this nice trick [here](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=36298)

```
export LOCPATH=$HOME/.wine/locale-ja/
mkdir -p $LOCPATH
localedef -f EUC-JP -i ja_JP $LOCPATH/ja_JP.EUC-JP
localedef -c -f SHIFT_JIS -i ja_JP $LOCPATH/ja_JP.SJIS
env LOCPATH=$HOME/.wine/locale-ja/ LANG=ja_JP.SJIS wine prog.exe
or alternatively 
env LOCPATH=$HOME/.wine/locale-ja/ LANG=ja_JP.EUC-JP wine prog.exe
```